# Construction of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, geometric-construction

I need to construct a triangle with given information:
$c = 6$, $h = 4$ and $\alpha - \beta = 30º$.

I'll put approximate result for any clarification.

[image]

Comment: Can you label or describe $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: I would guess that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the angles at points $A$ and $B$. But this needs to be stated clearly.

Comment: Yes, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are angles at points $A$ and $B$. I'll change picture. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: one way is to use sin(a-b) and cos(a-b) formula to get 2 equations and then solve them simultaneously

Comment: But the problem specifically says to construct a triagle. I know it's quite easily solvable by calculation.

Comment: with compass, scale?

Comment: with compass and ruler, of course. Normal euclidean geometry.

Comment: One can use calculus to find the coordinate of $C$ and then construct $C$ by compass and ruler :-). Anyhow, let's see how a pure euclidean geometry solution looks like.

Comment: btw, the radius of the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ is $2\sqrt{73}-8\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I claim that the triangle $\Delta ABC'$ in the diagram below is the desired triangle, and can be constructed geometrically without reference to trigonometry. See below the diagram for a description of the construction.

[image]

---

**Construction**

The main goal will to be to construct a triangle *similar* to the one desired, as from there it's easy to scale it up to size.

Start by constructing a $4\times 6$ rectangle $ABCD$, with $A$ in the lower LH corner and $|AB|=6.$ We may then construct an equilateral triangle $CDE$ with the vertex $E$ chosen to be below $CD$ (and in fact below $AB$ as well.) Draw a circle $S$ centered at $E$ that passes through both $C$ and $D$.

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $CD$, and label $A'$,$B'$ as the intersections of the circle $S$ and the lines $AM$, $BM$ respectively. From this we can construct the triangles $A'B'D$, $A'B'C$ which are symmetric across the line $EM$.

We now argue that both of these triangles are, up to reflection, similar to the one desired. Consider the rectangle $R$ formed with $A'B'$ as the lower horizontal segment and with the upper segment on the line $CD$. Since all four vertices lie along lines passing through $M$ and the four vertices of $ABCD$, we conclude that $R$ and $ABCD$ are similar figures. Hence the width and height of the rectangle---and moreover those of the two triangles inscribed within them---are in the ratio $6:4$ as desired.

Now, observe that $A'$ is on the circle $S$ and so $\angle CA'D$ is an inscribed angle of the circle $S$. By the inscribed angle theorem, its angle must be half of $\angle CED$---but $CED$ is an equilateral triangle by construction. Thus $\angle CED=60^\circ$ and so $\angle CA'D=30^\circ$. But this is identical to $\angle B'A'D-\angle B'A'C$. Thus we have constructed two triangles $A'B'C$ and $A'B'D$ which are both similar (up to reflection) to the desired triangle.

From here, all we need to do is rescale one of these triangles to have width $6$. This can be done by drawing a line passing through $A$ and parallel to $A'D$. This intersects $CD$ at a point $C'$. Observe finally that $\Delta ABC'$ and $\Delta A'B'C'$ are similar triangles through the point $M$; since $|AB|=6$, we conclude that $\Delta ABC'$ is the triangle we set out to construct.

Comment: I should point out that the reflection aspect of the above construction owes to @Mufasa 's answer above (it was most helpful!)

Comment: Small correction: The last step should be to draw a line through A parallel to A'D. Also this is pretty awesome, nice job.

Comment: @AlexZorn: Woops, fixed (though if that's my only slip, I'm quite content). And, thank you for the compliment---it was really bothering me that none of us could find a geometric construction, so figuring this out was quite satisfying. (Glad I did so rather than adding a bounty!)

Comment: @Semiclassical awesome job, thanks!
I've also found one solution using inversions, but this one is much more straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

I have been unable to find a straightforward geometric construction, but an algebraic one is not completely outrageous.

[image]

In the diagram, $\tan \alpha  = \frac{4}{x}$ and $\tan \beta  = \frac{4}{{6 - x}}$. From your desired $\alpha  - \beta  = {30^ \circ }$ we get

$$\frac{{\tan \alpha - \tan \beta }}{{1 + \tan \alpha \tan \beta }} = \tan {30^ \circ }$$

$$\frac{{\frac{4}{x} - \frac{4}{{6 - x}}}}{{1 + \frac{4}{x} \cdot \frac{4}{{6 - x}}}} = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}$$

$$\frac{{8x - 24}}{{{x^2} - 6x - 16}} = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}$$

$${x^2} + ( - 6 - 8\sqrt 3 )x + ( - 16 + 24\sqrt 3 ) = 0$$

$$x = \frac{{6 + 8\sqrt 3  \pm \sqrt {{{( - 6 - 8\sqrt 3 )}^2} - 4 \cdot 1 \cdot ( - 16 + 24\sqrt 3 )} }}{{2 \cdot 1}}$$

$$x = 3 + 4\sqrt 3  - \sqrt {73} $$

(The value using $+$ in the $\pm$ is clearly too large.)

That last is not extremely hard to construct, and once you have that the triangle is trivial to construct. Let me know if you need more details on the construction of $x$. ($\sqrt {73}$ can be the hypotenuse of a right triangle with sides $8$ and $3$.)

By the way, the approximate values we get are $x \approx 1.384199$, $\alpha \approx 70.911828^ \circ $, and $\beta \approx 40.911828^ \circ $.

**ADDED LATER:**

Here is the general solution given $c$ and $h$ for $\alpha  - \beta  = {30^ \circ }$:

$$x = \frac{c}{2} + h\sqrt 3  - \sqrt {{{\left( {\frac{c}{2}} \right)}^2} + {{\left( {2h} \right)}^2}} $$

I left the expression in the square root as it is to make it clear how to construct it as a hypotenuse.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, since all operations in calculating $x$ can be done with ruler and compass. Big thanks!

Comment: @markich: You are welcome! I made a Geogebra file showing the construction for the general case. It's complex enough that I don't want to add it here unless you ask for it. Ask if you want me to add it to my answer!

Comment: No need, I've already made Geogebra file myself :)

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of here is to somehow get $\alpha-\beta$ into the picture. One way would be to reflect the triangle about the perpendicular line going through the mid-point of AB as shown here:
[image: triangle]

So point C' is the reflection of point C. Then angles CAC' and CBC' are both equal to $\alpha-\beta=30$.

I don't know if this helps?

Comment: I've tried that, but it didn't take me much more closer to the solution...